# Blade laravel, htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I've a problem with login in another view:
I've another form in my aplication for the login, is a customize form, the problem is, when I try login in my aplication with the correct email, and password, everything it's ok, but, when I put wrong email, or password, Laravel have to give me something like: "Email's wrong" but, not, I got this:

> (2/2) ErrorException
>   htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/vagrant/Code/BDC/resources/views/home.blade.php)

My code is this:

```
    <form class="login-box__form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
     @if ($errors->has('email'))
     <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required autofocus>
 @if ($errors->has('password'))
 <span class="help-block">
    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Recordarme
</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Entrar</button>
<a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="login-box__lost">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
<a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="login-box__register">Registrarme</a>
<span>
 <a href="{{ url('auth/facebook') }}">Registro con <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
 <a href="#">Registro con <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
</span>
</form>
```

The form is in a popover, which is displayed when the user clicks on it.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to log your errors to see what it contains: `Log::info($errors->first('password'));` -- then look in your log file in your storage folder.

Comment: You can also check the PHP error log and the compiled view file (inside the storage/framework/views I think). Show us what you get so we can help you.

Comment: It's almost impossible found the exactly file with the log of the form that i'm using, there are almost 101 files!

Comment: Remove half part of file and check that you get error or not. I mean add/remove and get which part gives error ?